# play pause toggle in android listview

Tags: android, listview, toggle, adapter, android-imageview

I have a listview with a play image button in every row ...

**Play and Pause** function

```
@Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
   Product product = songList.get(position);
    if (product.paused) {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        product.paused=false;
    }else {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        product.paused = true;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This works fine and I have no problem...

But now what I need to achieve is to set the previously clicked position back into Play icon before setting the new position to Pause.

Can you help me with this, please !!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified Hitesh Gehlot's answer:

```
@Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    Product product = movieList.get(position);
    if (product.paused) {
        for(int i=0;i< movieList.size();i++)
        {
            movieList.get(i).setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
            movieList.get(i).paused = true;
        }
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        product.paused=false;
    }else {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        product.paused = true;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
 @Override
public void playPauseOnClick(int position) {
    Product product = songList.get(position);
    for(int i=0;i< songList.size();i++)
    {
        songList.get(i).product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        songList.get(i).product.paused = true;
    }

    if (product.paused) {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        product.paused = false;
    } else {
        product.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
        product.paused = true;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: It is working but now I can't set the selected one back into play Icon again after setting it to pause